# Headings shortcut in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

I use headings a lot in my document and I like to use the navigation pane to quickly look through them.  The "issue" is that the only way I know how to open the navigation pane is to hit ctrl+f and then go from the find tab back to headings.  I was wondering if I could save a click by using some sort of shortcut to open the headings tab directly without having to go through find.  It feel like there should be a way since when I close and then reopen it flashes to the heading section only to switch back to find.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe it would be possible, at least in Word 2010, but only by creating a VBA Macro that relies on some (freely available) code and assigning a keystroke to it. If you are in a position to do that, you could start by looking through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401948/program-the-navigation-pane-in-word-2010 and see how far you get.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Is there a shortcut to open the navigation pane?

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>,<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>K</kbd> to toggle (Open and close) the Navigation pane.

You can also open the Navigation pane by clicking the page count in the status bar.

Sources [Word 2013 Shortcuts](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Word_2013.html) and [Move around in a document using the Navigation pane](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Move-around-in-a-document-using-the-Navigation-pane-394787be-bca7-459b-894e-3f8511515e55)

Answer (score 18):

### **Headings shortcut in Word**

Below are some shortcut keys that work for "style headings" in Word and apparently these work from version 2007-2016. Additionally, you can look over the ["How to Assign a Shortcut Key to a Style in Word"](http://www.howtogeek.com/217833/how-to-assign-a-shortcut-key-to-a-style-in-word/) post for instructions to assign a shortcut key to a "style in Word" if this is more specifically what you're looking for as well.

> ### [Keyboard shortcuts for Microsoft Word on Windows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-word-on-windows-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
>
> > **Work with headings in Outline view**
> >
> > *To do this press. . .*
> >
> > - **Expand text under a heading:** <kbd>`ALT`</kbd>+<kbd>`SHIFT`</kbd>+`Plus Sign`
> > - **Collapse text under a heading:** <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+`Minus Sign`
> > - **Expand or collapse all text or headings:** <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`A`</kbd>
> > - **Show all headings with the Heading 1 style:** <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`1`</kbd>
> > - **Show all headings up to Heading n:** <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Shift`</kbd>+<kbd>`N`</kbd>
>
> ---
>
> > **Apply Styles to paragraphs**
> >
> > *To do this press. . .*
> >
> > - **Apply the Heading 1 style:** <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`1`</kbd>
> > - **Apply the Heading 2 style:** <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`2`</kbd>
> > - **Apply the Heading 3 style:** <kbd>`Alt`</kbd>+<kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`3`</kbd>
>
> <sub>[Source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-for-Microsoft-Word-2016-for-Windows-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2)</sub>

Comment: This answer, although useful, does not address the OP's question - which was " I was wondering if I could save a click by using some sort of shortcut to open the headings tab directly"

Comment: @DavidPostill If you look at my EDIT and see what I removed, I had the EXACT same thing your answer had before you added your answer, but I removed it as I interpreted that as Ctrl+F which they were already using was more effecient that Alt+W+K so I actually removed that part of my answer based on my interpretation. In any case, nice job for keeping that and interpretting the question differently but based on the wording, I have no idea why they see pressing 3 buttons is more efficient than pressing 2 unless they needed the page count or the links you provided.

Comment: Ah, OK. It think it was more the focus issue with ctrl+f that was annoying the OP.

Comment: funny. to add a bullet points we have the shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+L, but that opens up safari on mac...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a keyboard shortcut to open the Navigation pane with the Headings showing.

Right-click on the Ribbon or QAT and choose Customize the Ribbon...
In the Customize the Ribbon and keyboard shortcuts dialog, beside Keyboard shortcuts (lower left corner), click Customize...
In the Customize Keyboard dialog, under Categories, select View Tab.
In the Commands list, select NavPane.
In the "Press new shortcut key" box, enter the keyboard shortcut you want to use.
After making sure that "Currently assigned to" doesn't indicate that this shortcut is assigned to a function you would not want to lose, click Assign, then Close.
Click OK or Cancel (it doesn't matter) to close the Word Options dialog.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, at least in my Word 2016, Alt-W K does nearly do what the OP wanted:  it opens the Navigation panel **in the tab that you last used**, and if that was the Headings tab you will get the Headings tab again.  Whereas Ctrl-F always opens the panel in the search Results tab. Which is what annoys the OP (and me!).