# How to access headings list in Microsoft Word navigation pane using keyboard

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

Using keyboard only, how do I select a heading in the navigation pane of MS Word.

I can get to the headings section by typing `Ctrl-F Tab Tab`, this highlights the Headings tab, (see image below), but how do get into the list of headings so I can select one?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Headings shortcut in Word?](https://superuser.com/questions/1030827/headings-shortcut-in-word)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the navigation pane is currently showing Headings:

Press F6 to get into the navigation pane, arrow down to reach the heading you want, space to select it and to jump into the document at that spot.

You could also add two more tabs to your initial attempt, as that will also get you into the headings pane.

Comment: I tried Tab in my first attempt but the focus indicator disappeared, so I assumed it wasn't working.  But I see now two tabs puts the focus on the first list item.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking to apply a style.

If so, you can use the following keyboard shortcuts

Apply the Normal style: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Apply the Heading 1 style: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

Apply the Heading 2 style:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

Apply the Heading 3 style:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>

You can also display the Apply Styles task pane by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, or display the Styles task pane with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Comment: No, he wants to select on of the headings in the jump list.